# Python - Geomapping different Dataframe using country names only

Tags: python, geomap

I want to make geomaping from dataframe include only countries name no coordinations, how i can get coordinations for countries name so i can make geomapping

```
    country 1990            2000            2005            2010            2015
17  Brazil  1.270000e+11    1.230000e+11    1.200000e+11    1.180000e+11    1.170000e+11
```

Comment: You could use [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mapping.html) for this

Comment: Solved. Thank You